# Reduce the resources to calculate search function

Tags: vba, function, excel

I'm currently writing a function that does the following: Search a string for matches from a range of keywords. However my code is too inefficient and take too long to run. Is there any way to simplify it and make it less resource intensive?

```
Function SearchV(text As String, wordlist As Range)
Dim res As Variant
Dim match As Long

On Error Resume Next

For Each res In wordlist
match = InStr(UCase(text), UCase(res))

If match > 0 Then
SearchV = UCase(res)
Exit Function
End If

Next res

If match = 0 Then
SearchV = ""
End If
End Function
```

Comment: You could load `wordlist` into an array instead of reading cell by cell, and  convert `text` to upper case before the loop. You could also use `Find` or `Match` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I am providing another approach that splits the `text` into an array based on the spaces between words. I know you said there may be some periods or extra spaces (in the comment below), but I have factored those out and you can easily add to it to remove more wonky characters.

### Search Each Word in Text Approach

```
Function SearchV(text As String, wordlist As Range)

Dim arr() As String, x As Long, rYes As Range

arr() = Split(text, " ") 'split text into array of words based on space

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

    Dim sTest As String
    sTest = Replace(arr(i), ".", "") 'remove any periods
    sTest = Replace(sTest, " ", "") 'remove additional space

    Set rYes = wordlist.Find(sTest)

    If Not rYes Is Nothing Then

        SearchV = rYes
        Exit Function

    End If

Next

SearchV = ""

End Function
```

### Search Against Array Approach

Based on your comment to my (and others' answers) I modified it to loop through an array, instead of the range. This may, or may not, help with speed, but I thought to show it since I had an answer posted anyway and it may be worth testing. I also set some of the variables to UCase Strings ahead of time which could prove useful.

```
Function SearchV(text As String, wordlist As Range)

Dim arr() As Variant
Dim sTest As String, sAgainst As String

sAgainst = UCase$(text) 'set

arr() = wordlist

For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

    sTest = UCase$(arr(x, 1))

    If InStr(1, sAgainst, sTest) Then

        SearchV = sTest
        Exit Function

    End If

Next

SearchV = ""

End Function
```

Comment: thanks Scott, I get the idea, however I am trying to find something in the string not the range. IE: text = "John Doe aabbcd"  Wordlist: aabbcd, abcd

Comment: I just edited my answer based on your comments, but I don't know if it will make *that* much of a difference. I also had another question ... will the `text` always be a string of words separated by a space (e.g. - `John Doe aabbcd` or `My text has always has spaces`)?

Comment: Its usually Name, group, gender. Name and group seperated by space, with gender seperated by periods and spaces. Normally I would just use a long string manipulation formula but there are some variations such as the name could have multiple middle names and there could be spaces and periods after the group id. I tried setting an array instead and it helps some

Comment: I edited my answer with another approach that splits `text` into an array and searches each word against the `wordlist` range. That may be faster as well, since you are only looping through each word in 'text`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method Find as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)

Example:

```
Sub SearchV(text As String, wordlist As Range)

With ActiveSheet.Range(wordlist) 
    Set c = .Find(text)
End With

MsgBox c.value

End sub
```

Comment: Sorry I need to clarify. I'm trying to find whether the Text string contains words from the word list. The text string can contain multiple other words in it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i've updated my answer to better match the original question (where text has multiple words and wordlist is singular words).

This splits up text into an array, and only loops through those words and uses find to locate the word on the wordlist.

The draw back to this is that, the code will only list the last word it finds, if there are multiple matches.

```
Function SearchV2(text As String, wordlist As Range)
Dim match As Variant
Dim mywords() As String
Dim i As Long

mywords = Split(text, " ")


For i = LBound(mywords) To UBound(mywords)
Set match = wordlist.Find(mywords(i), , , xlPart, , False)

If Not match Is Nothing Then
    SearchV2 = UCase(match)
ElseIf i = UBound(mywords) Then
    SearchV2 = ""
End If

Next i


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Function SearchV(sTxt As String, rTrg As Range)
Dim rCll As Range, sWord As String, sResults As String
    For Each rCll In rTrg
        sWord = rCll.Value2
        If InStr(UCase(sTxt), UCase(sWord)) > 0 Then sResults = sResults & Chr(32) & sWord
    Next

    Rem Set Results
    SearchV = Trim(sResults)
End Function
```